# Hansen-like chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm trying to customize the `book` class chapter headings.
Something similar to [memoir `Hansen` chapter style](http://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/) might be cool.

But I'm quite stuck right now since I can't make the chapter title overlap the chapter number.
[image]
Here is the code I use.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \usefont{T1}{jkp}{b}{n}%
    \fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont%
    \color{DarkCyan}\raggedleft}

\newcommand{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}%
    \fontsize{22}{1pt}\selectfont%
    \color{Black}}

\newcommand\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 2pt \hfill \kern \z@}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \reset@font%
        \parbox{.2\textwidth}{\chapnumfont \thechapter }
        {\raggedleft\chaptitlefont #1\par\nobreak}%
        \par\nobreak
            \vspace*{20\p@}%
            \thickhrule
            \vskip 40\p@
            \vskip 100\p@
    }}
\makeatother
```

---

To extend the question, now that I realize the chapter number may not be visible enough, how would you do make the same thing but avoid the title overlapping the number?

Basically the same as below but the number on the other side.

[image]

This picture as been produced with the following code.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\vspace{50pt}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\filleft{\parbox{.2\textwidth}{\chapnumfont\color{chapnumcolor}\thechapter}}}
    {0pt}
    {\Huge{\parbox{.8\textwidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}}}[\vspace{2ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand you right, this approach with »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« accomplishes the style you want. Should also work with the `book` class.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document

\colorlet{chapnumcolor}{DarkCyan}
\newcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{jkp}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{100}{120}%
  \selectfont%
}
\newcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{22}{26}%
  \selectfont%
}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\filleft\parbox{0.35\textwidth}{\filleft\chapnumfont\color{chapnumcolor}\thechapter}\qquad}
{0pt}
{\filleft\llap{\parbox{\textwidth}{\filleft\chaptitlefont #1}}}
[\vspace{1pc}{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
    \blindtext  % drop in actual document
\end{document}
```

This is of course customizable and perhaps improvable here and there.

---

[image]

---

**Update**

With regard to the comment this is an approach which swaps chapter number and title. Note that the width for the heading has been chosen with respect to two-digit chapter numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document

\colorlet{chapnumcolor}{DarkCyan}
\newcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{jkp}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{100}{120}%
  \selectfont%
}
\newcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}%
  \fontsize{22}{26}%
  \selectfont%
}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\rlap{\parbox{\textwidth}{\filleft\chapnumfont\color{chapnumcolor}\thechapter}}}
{0pt}
{\rlap{\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{\filright\chaptitlefont #1}}}
[\vspace{1pc}{\titlerule[2pt]}\thispagestyle{empty}]

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
    \blindtext  % drop in actual document
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I've been trying to use the titlesec package with no success. Thank you very much for showing the way.

Comment: Once more, the second example is simply perfect. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig You're code doesn't work with a bibliography. It makes it appear as another appendix. I want the bibliography to be treated like the introduction or table of contents sections - is this possible? Thanks.