# Are there any useful packages for modyfing the way the chapter looks?

Tags: packages, chapters

I have fairly minimal 'bits-and-pieces' knowledge of LaTeX; I've only used it to write theses and technical documents. I want to use it to write a book, too, and in Word I designed the following chapter opening. I'm not asking for a fully-fledged code to produce this result, but some hints towards useful packages and/or documentation would be highly appreciated. The `fncychap` package didn't prove useful, neither did `titlesec`.

I'm using the `memoir` class, by the way.

[image: the look I'm going for.]

Comment: You could achieve that with `titlesec`, but I guess you'll need quite a bit of code to make it working like this. Would be interesting to know which class you're using, because some have their builtin methods to style headings.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm using `memoir`. I was thinking of using a drop-cap style thingy to get that chapter number using a minipage or something, but I have very little knowledge of how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This isn't quite the same but it might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142401

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, wow, thanks! That does indeed come quite close. And it confirms my notion of using a parbox to achieve that chapter number. Thank you very much! :)